# Headless WordPress BUT using Gutenberg blocks and ACF blocks, is it possible?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, headless-cms, jamstack

I am looking to branch out into the world of headless WordPress(WP). I have a project lined up and was hoping to use a JS front end on top of WP. I've found lots of articles around headless WP setup, however none of them seem to support Gutenberg blocks.

Does anyone have a good headless WP setup with a JS front end? I am not too picky, just want it to be robust, well supported and able to handle Gutenberg and ACF blocks.

Any help/info would be appreciated.

One path I have ventured down is attempting to do this with Gatsby(which seemed like it was possible a year or two ago), however have had limited success. I have followed their documentation for setting up the site and required plugins for both WP and Gatsby but are unable to locate blocks in the graphQL JSON. I've installed plugins such as graphQL Gutenberg but this throws an error. I am able to get ACF fields but that would only be helpful if I decided to build the site using ACF flexible content.

Comment: Where you able to solve your problem ?  WPEngine have some good tutorials revolving around faust.js .

Comment: Afraid not. Ended up moving away from headless and using [Sage 10](https://roots.io/sage/) starter theme with [ACF builder](https://github.com/StoutLogic/acf-builder). Great workflow for building custom block built sites.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution, without luck...

Answer (score 0):

I created FirmaSite App Solution. It is a development tool to help creating apps for iPhone, Android, Windows or macOS with headless WordPress;

https://app.firmasite.com/

A live example for a post content:
https://app.firmasite.com/gutenberg-editor/
will have it's content as a JSON block in REST API:
https://app.firmasite.com/wp-json/firmasite/v1/content?slug=/gutenberg-editor/

A live example for a category archives:
https://app.firmasite.com/category/demo-content/
will have it's content as a JSON block in REST API:
https://app.firmasite.com/wp-json/firmasite/v1/content?slug=/category/demo-content/

WordPress' new feature, Block-Based Template Parts such as post header,
footer or archive loop displays of infinite style possibility added to these JSON
results. So JSON files have all necessary parts of a specific WordPress content.
This revolutionary solution allows us to convert WordPress to static JSON
files. In future, planning to add Dexie.js indexedDB wrapper to the current
product so companies can create apps with better data accessibility that
works without public internet such as offline modes or private intranet
networks.

Some videos;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Y0R81QaO4A

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbTh2KvSHsQ

I got banned from WordPress groups in reddit, facebook etc whenever I introduce this. It's kinda hard for me to promote and find companies that is interested in it. (for reddit mods, I still have no idea why [this account](https://www.reddit.com/user/firmasite/) got banned.)